# Need to split a string in Bash separated by a colon and assign to variables

Tags: bash, shell

I have String that always has 4 'words'

```
Strings:With:Four:Words and spaces
```

and need to split it into 4 variables in Bash.
so..

```
var1="Strings"
var2="With"
var3="Four"
var4="Words and spaces"
```

how do I do this?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: BTW, `var4=Words and spaces` would run the command `and`, with `spaces` as its first argument, and `var4` set to `Words` in the environment. More accurate to write `var4='Words and spaces'` to show something that behaves equivalently to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `IFS=:` before `read`:

```
s='Strings:With:Four:Words'
IFS=: read -r var1 var2 var3 var4 <<< "$s"
echo "[$var1] [$var2] [$var3 [$var4]"
[Strings] [With] [Four [Words]
```